# Mysql Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import the table below using an sql file but I get

`#1005 - Can't create table 'ehr_se.patient_medication' (errno: 150)`

Can you please help me to fix it? Thank you in advance!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ehr_se`.`patient_medication` (

 `patient_medication_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `admission_id` INT NOT NULL ,
 `patient_id` INT NOT NULL ,
 `active_ingredient` VARCHAR( 45 ) NULL ,
 `active_ingredient_id_code` INT NULL ,
 `strength` INT NULL ,
 `pharmaceutical_dose_form` VARCHAR( 45 ) NULL ,
 `number_of_units_per_intake` INT NULL ,
 `frequency_of_intakes` INT NULL ,
 `duration_of_treatment` DATE NULL ,
 `date_of_onset_treatment` DATE NULL ,
 `start_date_of_treatment` DATE NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `patient_medication_id` ) ,
UNIQUE INDEX  `pat_med_id_UNIQUE` (  `patient_medication_id` ASC ) ,
INDEX  `med_admin_data` (  `admission_id` ASC ,  `patient_id` ASC ) ,
CONSTRAINT  `med_adm_data` FOREIGN KEY (  `admission_id` ,  `patient_id` ) REFERENCES  `ehr_se`.`admission_data` (
`admission_id` ,
`patient_id`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: Do a `SHOW WARNINGS` after the failed `CREATE`, that will provide you with more detailed information. There's probably no index on `(admission_id, patient_id)` on the parent table ... which is a requirement with InnoDB foreign keys ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to have in table `admission_data`, the fields `admission_id` and `patient_id` as one index.

Answer (score 0):

Check your reference keys

```
`ehr_se`.`admission_data` (
`admission_id` ,
`patient_id`
)
```

have exact type `INT`